# Query executing but no results

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to execute the following query via the "Run SQL query/queries on database" page in phpmyadmin:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `bindings` (
  `binding_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `game_id` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `layout_id` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `key_number` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `normal_action` varchar(128) default NULL,
  `normal_group` tinyint(2) unsigned default NULL,
  `shift_action` varchar(64) default NULL,
  `shift_group` tinyint(2) unsigned default NULL,
  `ctrl_action` varchar(64) default NULL,
  `ctrl_group` tinyint(2) unsigned default NULL,
  `alt_action` varchar(64) default NULL,
  `alt_group` tinyint(2) unsigned default NULL,
  `altgr_action` varchar(64) default NULL,
  `altgr_group` tinyint(2) unsigned default NULL,
  `extra_action` varchar(64) default NULL,
  `extra_group` tinyint(2) unsigned default NULL,
  `image_file` varchar(256) default NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`binding_id`),
  KEY `fk_layout_id` (`layout_id`),
  KEY `fk_game_id` (`game_id`),
  KEY `idx_combined_bindings` (`game_id`,`layout_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=11150 ;
```

The result is a green box and checkmark saying the query was executed successfully. However phpmyadmin still reports "No tables found in database". What is wrong with the query or the database? Thanks!

Note: the above query is part of a much larger dump that I want to import into the database.

Comment: I assume that before this query executes, the correct `USE $DBNAME` has been executed?  Otherwise you will create the table somewhere random, or possibly not at all.

Comment: I agree with @zebediah49 Indeed, you *won't* create any table if that's the case; MySQL throws an error: "No database selected"

Comment: Maybe a dumb question: do you have permissions to create tables in the database? (worth checking)

Comment: Sorry I didn't see your responses. I started over with a blank database and the dump executed fine, and all the tables appeared and worked as they should.

Comment: It's not a commit issue is it?  Are you running it in one window (uncommitted) Querying from a 2nd window in which the session/commit hasn't occurred?

Comment: No. I think the database became corrupt after a server upgrade. I created the database about two months ago. It was working fine then. When I went back and looked yesterday the website was spitting out PHP errors, and phpmyadmin reported no tables were present. This was not true at some level since I should have been able to import an old dump had the tables really not been there. That's why I suspect it got corrupted. So I deleted the whole database and started over from the old dump, and now it seems to be OK. Here's the website if it's helpful: http://isometricland.net/keyboard/keyboard.php

Answer (score 0):

Never mind. I dropped the database and started over with a blank one and everything is running fine now. Somehow things got messed up when my web host upgraded from mySQL 5.0.92 to mySQL 5.1.63. Sorry!